# "'MainViewModel' type must derive from DependencyObject"

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'm trying to reconfigure my MVVMLight SL5 app for MVVMLight WPF.
I think I have hooked up all the correct GalaSoft libs, but on startup I get the exception shown in the title.
It occurs in ViewModelLocator when getting the ViewModel for MainPage:

```
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            MainViewModel mvm = null;
            try
            {
                mvm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
            catch (Exception xx)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xx.Message);
            }
            return mvm;
        }
    }
```

The exception comes from the GetInstance() call.
MainPage is derived from Window; DataContext is set in the xaml.

```
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Any hints on what is going wrong would be appreciated....
(Targeting .Net 4.5, GalaSoft WPF4 libs v4.0.30319)

Comment: This usually comes from a trying to register a dependency property on a type that does not inherit DependencyObject. Inspect the full stack trace (including inner exceptions, recursively) and it should lead you to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, d.k.
+{"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
   + _innerException {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
     + _innerException {"The type initializer for 'IRUploader.ViewModel.MainViewModel' threw an exception."} {System.TypeInitializationException}
        + _innerException {"'MainViewModel' type must derive from DependencyObject."} 
Breakpoint in MainViewModel ctor is never hit.  MainViewModel derives from MVVMLight ViewModelBase.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a constructor breakpoint to be hit - the problem is probably in a line like `public static readonly DependencyProperty x = DependencyProperty.Register(...)`

Comment: Thanks. It seems this was the problem:            public static readonly DependencyProperty UserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "UserName", typeof(object), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));
Is "typeof(object)" the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When registering a Dependency Property, the `ownerType` must inherit from `DependencyObject`, which MainViewModel does not.

However, given that you are using MVVM Light and the property is called "UserName", I would recommend not using a Dependency Property at all. Instead, use a regular property with INotifyPropertyChanged. The `ViewModelBase` in MVVM light has `RaisePropertyChanged` to help you with this.

Dependency Properties are generally used for user controls. For binding to a viewmodel's data, INPC is usually the way to go.

Comment: "When registering a Dependency Property, the ownerType must inherit from DependencyObject, which MainViewModel does not."
Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense now.